# How can I dynamically set paths to files in project files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp

I try to understand how can I assign filepaths in for example index.html file to .css file in development and production environment. Maybe this example will demonstrate my concerns:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="./assets/less/style.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <!-- after building it should be ./style/style.css -->
    ...
</head>
...
</html>
```

My development folder structure (it is my project structure) looks like:

```
.
|
|-- app
|-- assets
    |-- less
        |-- style.css
        |-- ...
|-- ...
```

But compiled, packed and released by `gulp` task folder structure is:

```
.
|
|-- app
|-- style
    |-- style.css
|-- ...
```

How can I specify exact filepath in `index.html` where is my style/javascript/image file? This problem is generic and doesn't touch only `css` files.

Comment: Usually you inject some code in your html like `href="<% env.CSS_PATH %>"` or something like that.